# What is this Debug section in the .exe created by MSVC?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, exe, portable-executable

I'm trying to create the same executable using MSVC compiler in Visual Studio, no matter when it is compiled. That has many applications, including reproducibility and version control. However, it always saves the timestamp of when the .exe was created in its headers, and there doesn't seem to be an option in the compiler to turn that off. I tried using MinGW's strip tool, and noticed the timestamp of the File Hdr section is always set 0. However, besides setting the timestamp in the File Hdr, MSVC also sets it in a "Debug" section, as we can see in this PEBear screenshot:

[image]

GNU's strip tool isn't able to remove that. What is this section? How to remove it/turn if off. What is "POGO"?

Comment: Could be for [Profile-guided optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/profile-guided-optimizations). You may be able to turn that off.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/pogo/

Comment: As far as I can tell, all debug information, including pogo, are off, but debug section still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the linker flag:

```
/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO
```

Should remove that section from the exe.